# Batch file, create .txt for for each individual file with the same name

Tags: batch-file

How do I get a batch file that will create a .txt for each file with the same name, while also copying the filename into the created .txt file as well? 
I've tried using this following command but it doesn't copy the file name into the .txt file as well

```
@echo off
FOR %%G IN (*.zip) DO TYPE nul>"%%~nG.txt"
```

Comment: `echo %%G>"%%~nG.txt"`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, still the same result nothing in the .txt file

Comment: `for /f %%g in (*.zip) do type %%g >"%%~nG.txt"`

Comment: You'll probably have trouble with any special characters in the filenames (particularly `&`).  Otherwise I expect `for %%G in (*.zip) do echo %%G>"%%~nG.txt"` to work.

Comment: thanks it works but is it possible to not copy over the file format .zip?

Comment: The `~n` in `%%~nG` means "just the filename without the extension." I'm sure you can figure out what to do from there.

Comment: You can greatly improve your karma by posting the answer to your own question, if none of the folks who helped you get there want to bother with it.  I would also recommend taking the [tour] and following all the links.

Comment: How did you know to use `%%~nG` for the output file name but didn't understand how to use that for outputting the file name without the extension into the text file?

Answer (score 0):

These answered my question thanks

"You'll probably have trouble with any special characters in the filenames (particularly &). Otherwise I expect for %%G in (*.zip) do echo %%G>"%%~nG.txt" to work. – avery_larry"

and

"The ~n in %%~nG means "just the filename without the extension." I'm sure you can figure out what to do from there. – SomethingDark "